# Angular 14 and Bootsrap 5 working locally when deployed but not on online server

Tags: javascript, css, angular, deployment, bootstrap-5

I have an Angular (14.2.0) application along with bootstrap (5.2.3).

When I build the app and deploy it locally on IIS it works fine and everything is displaying correctly like below:
[image: Local App]

But as soon as I add it onto the online hosting server it doesn't work :[image: Prod]

I've installed bootstrap with the nmp command.

My index file look like this when build:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FairValue</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>@charset "UTF-8";:root{--bs-blue:#0d6efd;--bs-indigo:#6610f2;--bs-purple:#6f42c1;--bs-pink:#d63384;--bs-red:#dc3545;--bs-orange:#fd7e14;--bs-yellow:#ffc107;--bs-green:#198754;--bs-teal:#20c997;--bs-cyan:#0dcaf0;--bs-black:#000;--bs-white:#fff;--bs-gray:#6c757d;--bs-gray-dark:#343a40;--bs-gray-100:#f8f9fa;--bs-gray-200:#e9ecef;--bs-gray-300:#dee2e6;--bs-gray-400:#ced4da;--bs-gray-500:#adb5bd;--bs-gray-600:#6c757d;--bs-gray-700:#495057;--bs-gray-800:#343a40;--bs-gray-900:#212529;--bs-primary:#0d6efd;--bs-secondary:#6c757d;--bs-success:#198754;--bs-info:#0dcaf0;--bs-warning:#ffc107;--bs-danger:#dc3545;--bs-light:#f8f9fa;--bs-dark:#212529;--bs-primary-rgb:13, 110, 253;--bs-secondary-rgb:108, 117, 125;--bs-success-rgb:25, 135, 84;--bs-info-rgb:13, 202, 240;--bs-warning-rgb:255, 193, 7;--bs-danger-rgb:220, 53, 69;--bs-light-rgb:248, 249, 250;--bs-dark-rgb:33, 37, 41;--bs-white-rgb:255, 255, 255;--bs-black-rgb:0, 0, 0;--bs-body-color-rgb:33, 37, 41;--bs-body-bg-rgb:255, 255, 255;--bs-font-sans-serif:system-ui, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";--bs-font-monospace:SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;--bs-gradient:linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));--bs-body-font-family:var(--bs-font-sans-serif);--bs-body-font-size:1rem;--bs-body-font-weight:400;--bs-body-line-height:1.5;--bs-body-color:#212529;--bs-body-bg:#fff;--bs-border-width:1px;--bs-border-style:solid;--bs-border-color:#dee2e6;--bs-border-color-translucent:rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);--bs-border-radius:.375rem;--bs-border-radius-sm:.25rem;--bs-border-radius-lg:.5rem;--bs-border-radius-xl:1rem;--bs-border-radius-2xl:2rem;--bs-border-radius-pill:50rem;--bs-link-color:#0d6efd;--bs-link-hover-color:#0a58ca;--bs-code-color:#d63384;--bs-highlight-bg:#fff3cd}*,*:before,*:after{box-sizing:border-box}@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference){:root{scroll-behavior:smooth}}body{margin:0;font-family:var(--bs-body-font-family);font-size:var(--bs-body-font-size);font-weight:var(--bs-body-font-weight);line-height:var(--bs-body-line-height);color:var(--bs-body-color);text-align:var(--bs-body-text-align);background-color:var(--bs-body-bg);-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.0a53e70ae8d362c5.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.0a53e70ae8d362c5.css"></noscript></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.5b42ae0133fe0f8f.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.df47d0ca2f99368a.js" type="module"></script><script src="scripts.e8076bd22250257e.js" defer></script><script src="main.b3d80f33060ff749.js" type="module"></script>

</body></html>
```

I have no idea what might be causing this, is there a differnt way that I should include bootstrap in the project ?

Comment: in your `styles.css` file check if the bootstrap css was included there should be something like `Bootstrap  v5.2.3` at the top of the css file

Comment: @Balaji my styles.css is empty, can I add this in manually and do you maybe have an example of how to do so?

Comment: For angular + bootstrap try using [this library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap#readme) to reduce your bundle size

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how exactly you included bootstrap in angular, typically

`npm install --save bootstrap`

then in `angular.json` file add the following paths

```js
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
]
```